# Xcode: automatic link static library dependency to Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, static-linking

I've workspace with two project: static lib and cocoa application. Static library link some system frameworks(libcrypto.dylib) and include dynamic lib's .h files(openssl/bn.h openssl/rsa.h). My static library compiles successfully.

Cocoa application uses this static library and at compile time gives an error: "undefined symbols, symbols not found" (bn, new rsa etc).
But when I include libcrypto.dylib also into cocoa application project then there is no error.

Question: Xcode can do this automatically, by taking dependency from the static link library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is unfortunately no. It is common practice to include each single static library in the project that requires the code. That is just the way it is done.

There is an [interesting article](http://www.daveoncode.com/2011/06/25/xcode-project-dependencies-static-library-build-error-invalid-symbol-duplicate-arch-i386-armv6-armv7/) on how to handle multiple static libraries in an XCode project.

Comment: What I'm doing: I have link some static libraries to my application. Each static library requires the dynamic library. Why must I to link the dynamic library into my application if static libraries already use this dynamic?

Comment: Unfortunately you will need to do this manually. Your static library have references to other static libraries that need to be present since llvm will need to have all libraries and objects to make the final library during the make process.